# Google App Engine dev_appserver.py + Cloud Datastore Emulator: crash on startup without log warnings or errors (exit status 245)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk, dev-appserver

I'm trying to run the Google App Engine local development server (`dev_appserver.py`) together with the Cloud Datastore Emulator.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on WSL (Windows 11 Pro 22621.1265)
- `/usr/bin/python2 --version`: 2.7.18
- `./venv/bin/python2 --version`: 2.7.18
- `/usr/bin/python3 --version`: 3.10.6
- `/usr/bin/gcloud --version`:

```
Google Cloud SDK 418.0.0
alpha 2023.02.13
app-engine-python 1.9.101
beta 2023.02.13
bq 2.0.85
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.16
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.3.0
core 2023.02.13
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.20
```

- `/usr/bin/java --version`:

```
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Background: I'm migrating an existing Python 2 server to Python 3.

Minimal scenario to reproduce the problem:

`gae.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

export DATASTORE_DATASET=myproject
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8087
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8087/datastore
export DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8087
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=myproject

python2 \
    /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py \
    --runtime_python_path=/usr/bin/python3 \
    --application=myproject \
    --host=localhost \
    --port=8082 \
    --support_datastore_emulator=true \
    --require_indexes=true \
    --running_datastore_emulator_host=localhost:8087 \
    --datastore_emulator_port=8087 \
    --log_level=debug \
    --dev_appserver_log_level=debug \
    ./app.yaml
```

`datastore.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

gcloud beta emulators datastore start \
    --project=myproject \
    --host-port=localhost:8087 \
    --verbosity=debug
```

`app.yaml`:

```
# Same result with python35 python36 python37 python38 python39 python310 python311
runtime: python310
# Any other options are not changing the outcome
# app_engine_apis: true
# service: default
# entrypoint: python3 -m main
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
# The emulator never reaches the point to install dependencies
# appengine-python-standard>=1.0.0
# Flask==1.1.4
# MarkupSafe==2.0.1
```

`main.py`:

```
# The WSGI application is not run at all (regardless of the app.yaml options)
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8083, debug=True)
```

Set up and activate the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

`grpcio` is required by the emulator (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator):

```
pip2 install grpcio
```

To attempt starting the emulator, simply run:

```
./gae.sh
```

Which outputs:

```
WARNING:  Python 2 will soon be deprecated by the Google Cloud SDK
and may not function correctly. Please use Python version 3.5 and up.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

WARNING:  Python 2 will soon be deprecated by the Google Cloud SDK
and may not function correctly. Please use Python version 3.5 and up.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

INFO     2023-02-24 11:20:19,042 devappserver2.py:240] Using Cloud Datastore Emulator.
We are gradually rolling out the emulator as the default datastore implementation of dev_appserver.
If broken, you can temporarily disable it by --support_datastore_emulator=False
Read the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator
Help us validate that the feature is ready by taking this survey: <**edited out because not allowed on Stack Overflow**>
Report issues at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187272

INFO     2023-02-24 11:20:19,056 devappserver2.py:317] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2023-02-24 11:20:19,428 <string>:711] Detected environment variable DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8087, dev_appserver will speak to the Cloud Datastore emulator running on this address. The datastore_path /tmp/appengine.myproject.myname/datastore.db will be neglected.
If you want datastore to store on /tmp/appengine.myproject.myname/datastore.db, remove DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST from environment variables and restart dev_appserver
INFO     2023-02-24 11:20:19,610 <string>:384] Starting API server at: http://localhost:38867
```

At that point the process **ends**.

The only output warnings are the deprecation of Python 2 (but that's still required according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/tools/local-devserver-command?tab=python) and the one regarding `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`.

If I run `echo $?` (get the exit code) I get `245`.

`dev_appserver.py` will crash regardless of whether the Datastore emulator was started with:

```
./datastore.sh
```

Turning the Datastore Emulator off by simply setting `--support_datastore_emulator=false` in `gae.sh` starts the application perfectly well, but of course without Datastore emulation, so all related functionality will fail at runtime.

Comment: FYI - Since you've enabled bundled APIs, you don't actually need the datastore emulator. You can use the bundled API for datastore in your code and your App will write to a local datastore and you can view the contents by navigating to http://localhost:8000/datastore (or using whatever port you set for ```--admin_port```)

Comment: Thank you again @NoCommandLine, I confirm that after commenting out the `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`, `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH` and `DATASTORE_HOST` variables, and removing the `--running_datastore_emulator_host` option, at least the Datastore emulator seems to start, as also explicitly stated in the console output (notably `INFO: Local Datastore initialized` and `Dev App Server is now running.`). However the main process still crashes :( [details in the next comment]

Comment: [continues from previous comment] However what seems to happen is that a new process for the Datastore emulator gets forked, and does stay alive, but the main `dev_appserver.py` process still exits silently with `245`, so the application still doesn't work :'( In order to do a subsequent test I have to kill the forked `cloud_datastore_emulator` process manually. I've tried to add some debug messages in the devappserver2 library's modules, to trace the execution and find out what it is that I think terminates with an exception that probably gets suppressed, but I couldn't narrow it down...

Comment: Hi @Dario? Do you find out a way to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Sorry @secretlm I gave up, I thought I'd try again later in the year, hopefully with later versions of the SDK... If Google really completely drops support for Python 2 also on its servers and I won't have solved this problem by then, I'm planning to simply use a separate Datastore on a remote Python 3 GAE for testing (the application should work on the remote server, it's only the local emulator that fails), until I complete a migration to a new Nodejs/Firestore-based environment on which I've been working for some time... Thanks for putting a bounty on this question!

Comment: @secretlm - Start the datastore emulator. After the emulator is running, open a new shell and then run ```dev_appserver.py``` in the new shell

Comment: why are you starting a python2 interpreter in your gae.sh? I think, this requirement was dropped at some point by Google. What happens, when you start datastore.sh first (in a separate shell) and then start your gae.sh script without the python2? Or if you simply type  dev_appserver.py from a venv with python 3.x activated?

Comment: @ChristianPetersen that's what NoCommandLine suggested in his answer below, however the outcome that I described in my comment to it is still current unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Start the datastore emulator. After the emulator is running, open a **new** shell and then run dev_appserver.py in the new shell.

My experience with datastore emulator is that you need to open a new shell after starting the emulator/setting the environment variables for the its environment variables to apply.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck... I don't know if I'm allowed to update the question, but a few things have changed since I asked it (SDK 434): now I have to add `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` at the top of both `./datastore.sh` and `./gae.sh`, and I have to use `python3` in `./gae.sh`, otherwise `dev_appserver.py` raises `ERROR: Python 2 is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK`. Note that however `./gae.sh` still has to be run in a Python 2 virtual environment, not Python 3. [continues...]

Comment: [...continues] If I run `./gae.sh` in a Python 3 environment, it raises `RuntimeError: Cannot use the Cloud Datastore Emulator because the packaged grpcio is incompatible to this system. Please install grpcio using pip`, but `grpcio` is indeed installed via pip (double checked with `pip list`). All this happens as suggested by first running `./datastore.sh` in a shell, and then running `./gae.sh` in a new shell.